# coldfusion 5 and iis 6 custom 404 page no displaying

Tags: iis, coldfusion, web-config, http-status-code-404, custom-pages

**strong text**I need to display a custom 404 page to visitors when they attempt to visit an old article and redirect them to the new one. I have the following in the web.config for the site

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="/custom404error.cfm" mode="On">
    </customErrors>
</system.web>


<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/custom404error.cfm" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

When I run locally, Everything works great, however, I have ColdFusion 2016, and this project was written in ColdFusion 5. When I test on the proper servers, I hit a weird error, When the URL is something like `www.domain.com/fakearticle.aspx` my custom page pops up, however when the URL is `www.domain.com/fakearticle.cfm` or `www.domain.com/fakearticle.htm`, I get two different 404 error pages. My question is: Why am I getting 3 different error pages, and what can I do to my config file to fix this.

**UPDATE** Ive fixed it. I had some mixups between servers I was testing on. Deploying all my changes to the wrong server. It works as expected

Comment: On the ColdFusion 2016 server are you using the build in server? Or are they both using IIS? If you are using IIS what are the different IIS versions.

Comment: @James A Mohler They both use IIS on 2016 I use IIs 7, on production and where I test, they use IIs 6

Comment: is there a setting in the coldfusion admin for handling 404's? is that the one you're getting for the fakearticle.cfm? or maybe in the sites application .cfm/.cfc?

Comment: @luke I have left the "onMissingTemplate" section in ColdFusion administratior blank. The two errors I get for the .cfm and the .htm files are a generic coldfusion 404 and generic iis 404 respectively.

Comment: I thought I was the only person who tested the wrong stuff.